# How to increase the height of curve in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to increase the height of the curve but its left and right position should remain same. Just want to lift up from center to give it a shape like curve as height changes.

```
Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

      // Create coordinates of rectangle to bound ellipse. 
      int x = 93;
      int y = 136;
      int width = 320;
      int height = 50;

      // Create start and sweep angles on ellipse. 
      int startAngle = 0;
      int sweepAngle = -180;

      // Draw arc to screen.
 e.Graphics.DrawArc(blackPen, x, y, width, height, startAngle, sweepAngle);
```

Comment: I guess, call `e.Graphics.DrawArc` with increased height?

Comment: Please be more specific. The height of the arc should increase if you increase the value of `height`. Have you tried that? What happened? How was that different from what you wanted to happen? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Please note that DrawArc does not really draw 'curves'. It draw arcs, that is parts from an ellipse. For real/arbitrary curves use DrawCurve or DrawBezier!

Comment: See here [MSDN on drawing curces](http://www.yevol.com/en/vcsharp/applicationdesign/lesson14.htm)!

Comment: If you want to stay with DrawArc, increase the height and decrease y by the same amount!

Answer (score 2):

In the most direct way your problem can be solved like this:

```
int change = 0;
e.Graphics.DrawArc(blackPen, x, y-change, width, height+change, startAngle, sweepAngle);
```

By increasing the variable `change` the ellipse will curve up more and more:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    change += 10;  
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

But maybe you want more control over the shape? Let's have a look at the options:

Here are examples of the three 'curve' drawing methods:

**Curves, Beziers & Ellipses**
[image]

And here is the code to draw that image.

Please ignore the `Graphics.xxxTransform` calls! They only are meant to shift the curves a little bit upwards so they don't overlap too much to see them properly.

Also note that the curves in the first image are **not** completely convex. See the last part of the answer to see a `DrawCurve` call that avoids the concave segments!

The important part are the `Points`!  And just as the comments suggest, in the third part the ellipses are being changed by making the height larger and moving the top of the Rectangle up by the same amount.

The complexity `DrawArc` of and `DrawCurve` is pretty much equal; both are controlled by four integers with a rather clear meaning: They either make one rectangle or the corners of a symmetrical triangle. (Plus one counterpoint for the convex call.)

`DrawBezier` is more complex, especially since the controls point(s) are not actually on the resulting curve. They can be thought of force vectors that pull the line into a curved shape and are harder to calculate.

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

    Point a = new Point(0, 200);
    Point c = new Point(200, 200);
    for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, -5);
        Point b = new Point(100, 50 + i * 10);
        e.Graphics.DrawCurve(Pens.Maroon, new[] { a, b, c }, 0.7f);
    }
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

    Point pa = new Point(250, 200);
    Point pb = new Point(450, 200);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, -5);
        Point pc = new Point(350, 200 - i * 10);
        e.Graphics.DrawBezier(Pens.ForestGreen, pa, pc, pc, pb);
    }
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

    int x = 500;
    int y0 = 200;
    int w = 200;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, -5);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y0 - i * 10, w, 10 + i * 10);
        e.Graphics.DrawArc(Pens.DarkBlue, rect, -0, -180);
    }
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
}
```

Notes:

- The **Curve** (1st image) can be further controlled by the [`Tension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/3w58chwy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) parameter. The lower the tension the more pointed it gets, approaching 1f it makes the curve broader..
- The **Bezier** curve (2nd image) is using only one control point. (Twice.) The curve gets a little pointed this way. You can make it broader and broader by using two different points the move apart little by little..
- The **Ellipse** can't be controlled; it will always fill the bounding Rectangle.

Here is an example of varying the `Curves` and the `Beziers`:

[image]

The `Curves` are drawn with varying `Tensions`. Also I have used an overload that helps to get rid of the concave part at the start and end of the curve. The trick is to add a suitable extra point to the start and end and to tell the `DrawCurve` to leave out these 1st and last segments.

The simplest point to use (for both ends actually) is the counterpoint of the one at the top.

The `Beziers` are drawn using two control points, moving out and up a little.

Here is the code for the variations:

```
Point a = new Point(0, 200);
Point c = new Point(200, 200);
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, -5);
    Point b = new Point(100, 50);
    Point b0 = new Point(b.X, a.Y + (a.Y - b.Y));

    e.Graphics.DrawCurve(Pens.Maroon, new[] { b0, a, b, c, b0 }, 1, 2, 0.1f * i);
}
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();



Point pa = new Point(250, 200);
Point pb = new Point(450, 200);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, -5);
    Point ca = new Point(350 - i * 9, 100 - i * 5);
    Point cb = new Point(350 + i * 9, 100 - i * 5);
    e.Graphics.DrawBezier(Pens.ForestGreen, pa, ca, cb, pb);
}
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
```

Answer (score 0):

here was the solution just increase  value of y0 as  u increase the value of 
y0-i here i=20

```
  int x = 96;
  int y0 = 260;
  int w = 320;
   e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, -5);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y0 - 20 * 10, w, 10 + 20 * 10);
    e.Graphics.DrawArc(Pens.DarkBlue, rect, -0, -180);

  e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not an answer, just a confirmation of my answer. If you like you can add it to your question. Also please remove the `TranslateTransform` and `ResetTransform` from your code. It was only meant to demonstrate the varying plots better.

Comment: Usually this is not a good idea because you want the drawn pixels to __persist__. This means that they shouldn't go away when you have for example minimized the window. For persistence __all__ drawing must __either__ use the Paint's e.Graphics object __or__ it must draw into a __Bitmap__ that is shown in some control. For anything dynamic, like reacting to a button click the former way is the better one. Simply change the variable that controls the height (`change` in my answer) in the button click and call Invalidate on the control or form you are drawing on! See my updated answer!